# print out an array list of custom objects made from own class in java

Tags: java, arraylist, printing

I am trying to print out a customer array list. I have created a customer class as well.
It's initialized by this

```
    List<Customer> listOfCustomers = new ArrayList();
    Customer customer = new Customer(customerLicense);
```

I then add a date, amount paid, expiration time to the customer then add the customer to the list

```
    listOfCustomers.add(customer);
```

I've tried a few different ways of printing it, but this got me the farthest.

```
    Object[] newListCustomers = listOfCustomers.toArray();
    Arrays.asList(newListCustomers).toArray(new String[newListCustomers.length]);
    for (int customerNumber = 0; customerNumber < newListCustomers.length; customerNumber++) {
        System.out.println(newListCustomers[customerNumber]);
    }
```

it gives an error `"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException"` on the line with the `Arrays.aslist()` function. Is there a better and easier way to print it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [foreach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop.

```
for (Customer elem_ : listOfCustomers) {
       System.out.println(elem_.name);
}
```